# Accessing ORDS Rest API in VBCS with Internal Certificate

Tags: oracle

We are trying to create a rest api in ords and want to consume same in VBCS application through Service Connection > Define by EndPoint.

Below is the rest API URL

http://130.162.66.7/ords/ssopdb1/ssowsp/test3/alldata/data

and we are getting the below error in VBCS while doing test on the connection.  We imported root cert in ICS instance as this VBCS is came along with ICS instance.

```
{

    "type": "abcs://proxy_auth_problem/ssl/handshake",

    "title": "SSL Error",

    "detail": "A problem was reported making a SSL connection because of 'General SSLEngine problem'",

    "status": 502

}
```

Someone please help me with the above error.  Is there anyway we can add trusted certificates in VBCS.

Comment: Don't. On your ORDS server assign a real DNS and get a real certificate for that dns name.

Comment: How do you run VBCS?  I'm assuming you are running a user managed VBCS with a user managed 12c Oracle Database underneath, correct?  In the PSM console, cant you simply open up the https port?

Answer (score 0):

VBCS needs a secure SSL connection to your ORDS service - so you need to install a valid SSL certificate there.
Refer:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbi/administer-ords.html#GUID-A9852DA6-B16C-4369-A186-9482B31C9786
- https://blogs.oracle.com/dbaas/installing-a-trusted-ssl-certificate-on-oracle-database-cloud-service-for-apex

Answer (score 0):

You can register a self signed certificate with VB and ORDS: https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/connecting-vbcs-to-ords-with-self-signed-certificates-for-development